# Settings.bundle does not update on AppStore

Tags: iphone, settings, distribution

I have an application for which a new release is now available from the AppStore. The strange thing is that the general settings are still the one of the first version...

I have added a new item and modified an other one. On my testing iPhone, either in debug or release mode, I see the new settings.

Before compiling for publishing, I did a Clean All Targets... But it behaves like if the old Settings.bundle had been published instead of the new one.

Did someone face this already? I am ready to publish a new release to fix it, but how could I be sure that it will not happen again?...

Any advises will be welcome.
Thanks in advance,

Fred

Answer (score 0):

I am having almost exactly the same problem.  In this case, however, my original app never had a Settings Bundle, and now when I deploy to a device - even with a Clean All Targets - I cannot get my settings bundle to show.  My app is for iPad, and I can't afford to ask people to delete their old apps and reinstall.  I'm going to peruse the rest of Stack Overflow and see if I can find an answer to our problem.

Comment: Hi Smorpheus,

I made a small step since I post this question. I have seen that it is possible to open the packet (not sure of the translation for this word) of my submitted app. Then, by checking date and size of the enclosed files, it was obvious that I had sent the old settings.bundle file. As I did a "Clean All..", I don't understand how it happened, but I know how to check if everything is correct before submitting again. Have you checked into the distribution file, if the settings are there? HTH

Comment: Actually, I've decided to just go ahead and do my own in-App settings system as I think it will be more useful to users anyway.  Thank you for the info, and I will keep it in mind in the future when I am submitting apps.

Were you able to get the correct bundle attached to your resubmission?

Comment: Yes. I never got that problem but I always check before submitting if it is present and if the date is correct. And you? Did you find why the file was missing?